# How to pass variable from twig to js?

Tags: javascript, php, twig

Code prints out tasks information. I want to pass tasks array to JS. How could I do that? Some of my twig code:

```
    <div>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td id>{{ task.Id }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Status }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Description }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Category }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.Author }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.CreationDate|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
                <td><a id="myLink" href="/edit/{{ task.ID }}" > Edit </a></td>
                <td><a id="myLink" href="/delete/{{ task.ID }}" >Delete</a></td>
                <?php echo 2+2; ?>            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
</div>
```

I want to pass array to this js class:

```
$(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    });
});
```

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista Yes, I did :)

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize the array in json format: `{{ tasks | json_encode() }}`.

If your javascript is inside a `<script>` element of the twig template, you can just do: `var data = {{ tasks | json_encode() }}`.

Otherwise, you can put the serialized array somewhere in the twig template as an element's attribute:
`<div id="data-element" data-tasks="{{ tasks | json_encode() }}">`.
Then just get the data with

```
var jsonString = $('#data-element').data('tasks');
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you need to know that there are a big deference between PHP arrays and Javascript arrays.

you need to convert your array to a common understood format that both PHP and Javascript can understand , which is `JSON` .

so I will assume that you are sending your tasks from your controller to twig as a json format, then you can set your javascript variable as follows :

```
<script>
var tasks = '{{ tasks }}';
var tasksObj = JSON.parse(tasks); // to convert json into a javascript object
</script>
```